# LaTeX Workshop autobuild stops on Tex errors

Tags: latex-workshop

I began using VSCode for writing LaTeX documents, and the LaTeX Workshop plugin seems promising. However, while using it, I encountered an issue for which I haven't found a solution yet.

When I write something in a `.tex` file and press `Ctrl+S` to save it, I can instantly see the change in the compiled PDF with `latexmk`.

The problem arises when I make a syntactical mistake in a `.tex` file and press `Ctrl+S` to save it; the build process halts with an error.

[image]

Once I encounter this error, regardless of whether I fix it, `Ctrl+S` no longer triggers the auto-build process for the project. I have to close VSCode and reopen it to restore the auto-build functionality.

Is there a solution to get the auto build running after the error is fixed and without having to restart VSCode?

To add to this, in the logs I can see a message `Do not use Docker to invoke the command: path/to/latexmk` and the log just hangs there.

Comment: Try `latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex` but i'm not sure....

Comment: These arguments are already there with `latexmk` in `settings.json` `-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=%OUTDIR% %DOC%`

Comment: Did you setup the `latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run` to `onSave`? I've always found it buggy. Also, does the problem persist (need to relaunch) if you trigger the clean command?

Comment: `autoBuild.run` is set to `onSave` and it seems to be working fine as when I save a file, the change is reflected in the pdf almost instantly. However if I make any TeX error (like an undefined reference or citation or wrong command), build fails and cannot reinstate autobuild on save; even after `clean` command.

Comment: Does it compile after an error if you use the cmand from the LaTeX Workshop side panel which deletes all temporary files?

Comment: At first the `"latex-workshop.latex.clean.command"` in `settings.json` was blank by default. Now I have set it to `latexmk` (following the default at https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-workshoplatexcleancommand). It looks like now it auto builds once the syntax errors are fixed. I will see if that change fixed this behaviour and update here.